# Angular Translate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-translate

Here's [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/85/)

Is it possible in angular-translate to check if in other language key-value is not available then it can pull that key-value from another language ?
Like in example i have English and Spanish. And One key-value ("CONFIRM_LABEL" in example) is not available in Spanish. Is it possible to pull that data from English version ?

HTML

```
<div name="info" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <label translate="TERMS_LABEL"></label>
    <h4 translate="ZIPCODE_LABEL"></h4>
    <p translate="LAST_NAME"></p> 
    <p translate="CONFIRM_LABEL"></p>
  <button type="submit"  ng-click="changeLanguage('de')" >Spanish</button>
   <button type="submit"  ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" >English</button>
```

js

```
    var demo = angular.module('demo', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
   demo.controller('myctrl',function ($scope,$translate) 
       {
        $scope.changeLanguage = function (key)
        {
         $translate.use(key);
        };
 })

 demo.config(function ($translateProvider) {
   $translateProvider.translations('en', {

        "TERMS_CONDITIONS":"TERMS & CONDITIONS",
        "TERMS_LABEL":"TERMS",
       "ZIPCODE_LABEL":"ZIP CODE",
       "LAST_NAME":"Last Name",
       "CONFIRM_LABEL": "Confirm Number ",

    })
   .translations('de', {

            "TERMS_LABEL": "Términos",
            "FORM_LABEL": "Información ",
            "LAST_NAME": "Apellido",
            "ZIPCODE_LABEL": "Código Postal"
   });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Use [fallback languages](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/08_fallback-languages):

```
$translateProvider
    .translations('de', { /* ... */ })
    .translations('en', { /* ... */ })
    .fallbackLanguage('en');
```